# Change Winsock.LocalIP on run time

Tags: vb6, ip-address, winsock

I have a problem with the Winsock control.
The problem is that I can't set the right IP for the localIp property.
It becomes relevant when I have some LAN adapters (logical like vmware or physical).
I have a way to know what is the right ip.

Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bind Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228076%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

```
Winsock1.Bind LocalIP:="127.0.0.1"
```